# Uniform Convergence and exponential inequality to demonstrate Stirling's formula

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions

If $0<R\leq\sqrt n$ and $Z_{k} \sim exp(1)$ are independent and identically distributed as prove that $$P\left[\left|\dfrac{Z_{1}+Z_{2}+\cdots +Z_{n} -n}{\sqrt n }\right|\leq R\right] \geq 1- \dfrac{1}{R^{2}}$$ and in addition must show that $g_{n}(\sigma)= (n-1)\ln\left(1+\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}\right)-\sqrt n \sigma + \dfrac{\sigma^{2}}{2}$ uniformly converges to zero in the interval $-R<\sigma <R.$

I'm trying to prove probabilistically Stirling's formula and I can not make that part up! Can anyone help me?

Comment: By Stirling's Formula, do you mean $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\dfrac{n^n}{e^n}$?

Comment: Yes, if I can solve this part terminate the demonstration of a probabilistic way!